# ¿Cómo puedo obtener números de teléfono de una página de Google Maps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps, beautifulsoup

Quiero raspar el número de teléfono de los resultados de google maps:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/EDF+Cap+Amp%C3%A8re/@48.9204621,2.3433823,17z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x47e66ec170a20129:0x644cff7266591e49!8m2!3d48.9204621!4d2.3433823!16s%2Fg%2F1wv_rjhy

Que está a la izquierda aquí:

[image]

Puede que los tengamos aquí.

```
<div jstcache="258" class="Io6YTe fontBodyMedium" jsan="7.Io6YTe,7.fontBodyMedium">05 61 93 70 00</div>
```

Luego probé con

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

nom_entreprise = "AIRBUS"
adresse = "2 RPT EMILE DEWOITINE, BLAGNAC"


url = f"https://www.google.com/maps/search/{nom_entreprise},{adresse}"
print(url)
 
# Faire une requête GET sur la page de résultats de recherche Google
page = requests.get(URL)
# Envoi de la requête et récupération du contenu HTML
response = requests.get(url)
content = response.content

# Analyse du contenu HTML avec BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

# Recherche des éléments contenant les numéros de téléphone
phone_numbers = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'Io6YTe fontBodyMedium'})
print(phone_numbers)
# Affichage des numéros de téléphone trouvés
for phone_number in phone_numbers:
    print(phone_number.text)
```

Pero no puedo traer de vuelta nada como me devuelve una página no relacionada en holandés. De hecho, esto es lo que tengo en `soup`.

[image]

Comment: Si utilizo `wget` para descargar el URL que muestras, el HTML que recibo no contiene número de teléfono alguno, sino un mensaje de Google con su política de cookies y un botón para aceptarla. Probablemente por esto no te funciona el scraping (y a saber si, una vez aceptada la política, la página que recibes realmente contiene el teléfono como parte de un HTML estático o por el contrario el html se crea dinámicamente con peticiones AJAX y respuestas JSON)

Comment: Confirmado, como era de suponer, aún si consiguieras pasar la página de la política de cookies, la página final que muestras en la primera captura no es el resultado de un GET, sino de multitud de peticiones ajax y procesamiento de datos en javascript y posterior manipulación del DOM. No puedes emular nada de eso desde requests/beautifulsoup. Lo mejor será que uses la API de google (aunque me temo que requiere un registro con una tarjeta de crédito)